# Efficient way to get unique values from records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id int identity not null primary key,
code nvarchar(50),
name nvarchar(50),
node_code nvarchar(50),
parent_node nvarchar(50),
prop1 int,
prop2 datetime,
prop3 nvarchar(50)
);
```

The code and name is correlated, and they form a key to the properties. So the table could contain the following data:

```
CODE001 NAME001 [3 PROPS]
CODE001 NAME001 [3 PROPS]
CODE002 NAME002 [3 PROPS]
CODE002 NAME002 [3 PROPS]
...
```

I know this is not a good design, but I have to live with it.

The question now is I want to get the list of code name along with their node code and parent node code (the node code is unique to code and name key), but not with properties. I can do this:

```
select DISTINCT code, name, node_code, parent_code from test
```

But I seriously doubt if this is the most efficent way. I need suggestions.

Comment: select code, name, node_code, parent_code from  test  group by code,name,node_code, parent_code. This is how I get unique values instead of using distinct. Donno about most efficient method though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT code, name, node_code, parent_code ,prop1, prop2, prop3 FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code, name, node_code, parent_code ORDER BY code, name, node_code, parent_code) AS RN,
        code, name, node_code, parent_code,prop1,prop2,prop3
    FROM test
) TEST2
WHERE TEST2.RN = 1
```

You can study more about this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this SQL statement appears to be very slow agaist 2 million records. The following SQL is quite fast (1 second):

    select a.code,
       (select top 1 name from test where code = a.code),
       (select top 1 node_code from test where code = a.code),
       (select top 1 parent_code from test where code = a.code)
    from test
    order by a.code